# ¿Cómo saber el número de peticiones ajax activas con jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

¿Cómo puedo conocer el número de peticiones ajax activas usando jQuery?

Tenía entendido que `jQuery.active` daba ese valor, pero no está funcionando.

En un punto de una aplicación, disparo un evento personalizado con jQuery:

```
$('body').trigger('association:change');
```

Varios procesos están a la espera de dicho evento, y cada uno realiza una petición ajax por su cuenta, lo que puede resultar en varias peticiones simultáneas. Para indicar al usuario que el sistema se encuentra realizando operaciones, muestro una animación de tipo "loading". Cuando la última de las peticiones acaba, debe ocultar esta animación. Hasta el momento, creía que con

```
if ($.active < 1) {
    $('.loading').hide();
}
```

podría conseguirlo. ¿Hay alguna forma de conocer el número de peticiones ajax no finalizadas con jQuery?

Comment: Gracias @OscarGarcia! Finalmente la solución vino de la mano de la respuesta que he publicado, no la he podido marcar como correcta hasta hoy por limitaciones de la plataforma. No obstante tu respuesta resultó muy útil y aclaratoria y por ello tiene un voto positivo por mi parte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente lo he solucionado por otra vía, aunque la opción de los eventos ajaxStart/ajaxStop es también bastante interesante.

Usando el jQuery.when().then(); puedo llegar al mismo fin que iba buscando, y para mi gusto, de forma bastante más limpia de lo que intentaba antes.

```
  $('body').on('association:change', function () {

        $('.loading').show(); // Aquí empezamos la animación.

        $.when(
            $.get(updateUrl1, function(data)) { // Primer elemento de tipo "deferred"
                 // some code here
                 $obj1.html(data);
                 // some code here
            }),
            $.get(updateUrl2, function(data)) { // Segundo elemento de tipo "deferred"
                 // some code here
                 $obj2.html(data);
                 // some code here
            }),
            $.get(updateUrl3, function(data)) { // Tercer elemento de tipo "deferred"
                 // some code here
                 $obj3.html(data);
                 // some code here
            })
        ).then(function(){
            $('.loading').hide();
        });

  });
```

No es la solución que buscábamos en un principio, pero se adapta bastante bien al resultado esperado.

Comment: Es muy llamativo que publiques una respuesta con parte del código omitido en la pregunta inicial. Creo que si hubieses agregado esta parte del código podrías haber recibido mejores respuestas (o mas adecuadas). En la pregunta has detallado que "_Varios procesos están a la espera de dicho evento_", en tu respuesta, solo se puede visualizar un solo `listener`.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo +1, con código hubiera sido más fácil reproducir el error y corregirlo :/ PD: He editado mi respuesta con una prueba de concepto aplicando mi respuesta a tu código (con otro evento más sencillo de reproducir).

Comment: @MarcosGallardo no ha sido una omisión intencionada. Con el nuevo planteamiento ha surgido. Distinta ejecución, mismo resultado.

Comment: @Muriano, entiendo que has modificado el funcionamiento para solucionarlo, pero esta respuesta no soluciona el planteo de la pregunta, ya que si tuvieras "_Varios procesos están a la espera de dicho evento_" aún tendrías el problema.

Answer (score 5):

Para hacer la tarea que deseas tienes disponible [`ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/):

> **Description:**
>
> Register a handler to be called when all Ajax requests
>   have completed.

Incluyendo también el inicio de la carga, el código quedaría algo así:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $('.loading').show();
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  $('.loading').hide();
});
```

He estado investigando en el código de jQuery el uso de [`jQuery.active`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L295) y debería informar del número de conexiones que están sin finalizar, pero depende del lugar y/o momento en el que accedas a esa propiedad [contendrá lo que esperas o no](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L815) ya que se decrementa su valor al final del evento [`done`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L709), por lo que si intentas acceder a ese valor durante la ejecución de un `callback` de `done` no tendrás el valor actualizado (por ponerte un ejemplo).

Por cierto, para que se lleven bien las cuentas, asegúrate de que todas las peticiones AJAX están adosadas a `document`:

> As of jQuery 1.9, all the handlers for the [jQuery global Ajax events](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/),
>   including those added with the `.ajaxStart()` method, must be attached
>   to `document`.

---

Edito: He desarrollado una prueba de concepto en la que puedes comprobar que funciona correctamente mi propuesta:

```js
/* Eventos de comienzo y final con cambios de color */
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  console.log("Inicio");
  $('.loading').show();
  $('body').addClass('rojo');
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  console.log("Fin");
  $('.loading').hide();
  $('body').removeClass('rojo');
});
/* Llamadas Ajax al pulsar el texto */
var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/';
$('#pruebas').on('click', function() {
  $.when(
    $.get(url + '1', function(data) {
      console.log("Fin 1. Quedan: " + $.active);
    }),
    $.get(url, function(data) {
      console.log("Fin 2. Quedan: " + $.active);
    }),
    $.get(url + '3', function(data) {
      console.log("Fin 3. Quedan: " + $.active);
    })
  ).then(function() {
    console.log("Then. Quedan: " + $.active);
  });
});
```

```css
.loading {
  display: none;
}
.rojo {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pruebas">Pulse para iniciar las pruebas</div>
<div class="loading">Cargando</div>
```

También podrás ver lo que dije. Durante la ejecución del evento `success/done` el contador aún no ha sido decrementado, por lo que el último verá un valor de `$.active` de 1, en vez de 0, incluso dentro del bloque `.when()` del final.

Comment: Algo importante es que si `$.ajax()` o `$.ajaxSetup()` es llamado con la opción `global: false`, los métodos `.ajaxStart()` y `.ajaxStop()`  no será ejecutados.

Comment: Lo siento, no me sirve. No todas las peticiones ajax que se realizan en el script activan la animación de loading.

Comment: Es probable que sea porque las estás adosando a otro elemento del DOM que no sea `document`. Se podría depurar el problema agregando código de depuración a la biblioteca `jQuery` alrededor de las líneas que te marqué en mi respuesta, pero no puedo ayudarte más sin el código que genera las consultas Ajax. PD: Gracias por el detalle @Marcos Gallardo, más detalles [AQUÍ](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L575).

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Justo antes de disparar el evento `association:change`, utilizando el método [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) suscribirte a los eventos [`ajaxStart` y `ajaxStop`](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/)
- Cuando `ajaxStop` se dispare, utilizas [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) para de-suscribirte.

Así por ejemplo:

```
// Attach to ajax events
$(document)
  .on('ajaxStart', onAjaxStart)
  .on('ajaxStop', onAjaxStop);

$('body').trigger('association:change');

// Hoisted functions

function onAjaxStart() {
  $('.loading').show();
}
function onAjaxStop() {
  $('.loading').hide();
  $(document)
    .off('ajaxStart', onAjaxStart)
    .off('ajaxStop', onAjaxStop);
}
```

**PD1**: Si `$.ajax()` o `$.ajaxSetup()` es llamado con la opción `global: false`, los eventos `ajaxStart` y `ajaxStop` no será disparados.

**PD2**: Ya que utilizas eventos para disparar acciones, podrías crear un nuevo evento (eg: `loader:ajax`), para mostrar automáticamente el `loader`.